# How can I fetch content from a particular html div from a list of URLs in a dataframe using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am analyzing text from a specific div in several URLs.

All examples I've found ask for input of a single URL but in my case I am working in bulk.

Any suggestions?

Comment: if that's the case, you can try writing a function which inputs url. And you and iterate this function with the list of urls you have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's split this problem in parts.

First we want to fetch a single URL and return its corresponding HTML document.
Doing this separately also allows us to handle errors and timeouts in a transparent way.

```
def get_raw_content(url):
     tmp = requests.get(r.url, timeout=10)
     return tmp.content if tmp.status_code == 200 else None
```

Next comes the interesting bit. Given a single HTML document, we now want to fetch the content for a particular div. This is where your original code should be.

You could also use XPATH for this. But BeautifulSoup does not support XPATH.
I've written a module that provides a simple XPATH interpreter for bs4 though. If you need that, just let me know in the comments.

```
def get_div_content(url):

    # first fetch the content for this URL
    html_text = get_raw_content(url)
    if html_text is None:
        return None

    # work with beautiful soup to fetch the content you need
    # TODO : insert your code for 1 URL here
    return None
```

Now, as indicated by other comments, we simply iterate over all URLs we have, and execute the code for a single URL on each one in turn.

```
def fetch_all(urls):
    for url in urls:
        txt = get_div_content(url)
        print('{} {}'.format(url, txt))
```

Lastly, we need some entrypoint for the python script.
So I've provided this main method.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fetch_all(['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.bing.com'])
```

Comment: Hi Joris, thank you for the feedback. Would it be posible for you to share the xpath interpreter module? Thanks again.

Comment: If this answer works for you, please take the time to mark it as the accepted answer. That way other users also benefit by knowing this problem can be solved in the suggested fashion.